# Making method not change its own class variables without making them constant

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose there are variables in a class and the method of that class should not change the member variables without making the variables constant.
How can it be achieve - if it is possible?

Comment: Make the member function `const`.

Comment: Is this a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This doesn't look like XY problem to me. Constant member methods are common, aren't they? There can be multiple reasons behind it.

Comment: @taskinoor, I am assuming the OP knows about `const` member functions. Could be a bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Use constant method. For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    // this won't be able to change any member variable
    void bar() const;
}

void Foo::bar() const {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `const`-qualify  the member function:

```
struct X {
    int a;

    void f() const {
        // a = 42; // illegal
    }
};
```